# Capture click events in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt5

The `QObject::connect` statement in the brief code below displays

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
QTableView::clicked(QModelIndex) --> QTextEdit::setText(QString)
```

How would one capture the name (foo, bar) from the entry in QTableView and display that name in the QTextEdit in the adjacent pane?

```
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QSplitter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Left Pane: Model
    QStandardItemModel * tableModel = new QStandardItemModel(2, 1);
    const char *name[2] = { "foo", "bar" };
    for(int row=0; row<2; ++row) {
        QString namestr = QString("%1").arg(name[row]);
        QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem(namestr);
        item->setEditable(false);
        tableModel->setItem(row, /*col*/0, item);
    }

    // Left Pane: View
    QTableView * tableView = new QTableView;
    tableView->setModel(tableModel);
    tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    tableView->adjustSize();
    tableView->show();

    // Right Pane
    QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit("Uninitialized");

    QObject::connect(tableView, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), textEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));

    QSplitter splitter;
    splitter.addWidget(tableView);
    splitter.addWidget(textEdit);
    splitter.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Also, I vaguely recall reading that an alternative method (proofed during compilation) will be available to handle events in Qt 5.x. If that's the case, a hint to a solution in that idiom would be even nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You cannot connect a signal to a slot with incompatible arguments. You need to create either a slot in a `QObject`-based class or a non-member function. This function should have `QModelIndex` argument. Connect `QTableView::clicked(QModelIndex)` to that function. In the function you can set new text for text edit using `textEdit->setText(index.data().toString());`.

You need to ensure that `textEdit` variable is accessible in the function, e.g. if the function is a class member, you also need to make `textEdit` a class member. It's convenient to create a Designer form class using Qt Creator and create a slot in the class using Designer interface.

Comment: Connecting to a member function slot in a MyTextEdit works fine, although adding another compilation unit to this trivial example was necessary. Taking the nonmember function approach is not yet right.